# How to play my uploaded video on schedule on my website

Tags: php, html, wordpress

One of my client wants to have live stream player which play his uploaded video on time..
I am asking wether its possible as I have embedded channels,live broadcast but no experience in playing uploaded video on time.
here is the question from her
2.Need the ability to upload and delete the videos in the admin end.

3.Need to set the Time/Date schedule for particular video to get play .

4.The player need to get play in all MAC products and Android too.

I will be waiting for your reply.
Thanks
Nauman K

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty complex so I will try to answer only the main problem: streaming the video only after specific date.

What I would do is saving the information about scheduled air time somewhere in the database and then use the PHP to stream the contents of the file to the player of your choice.

```
$video = new Video('nameOftheFile');

if($video->isScheduled()) {
    if($video->onAir())
        $video->stream();
    else {
        $waitingVideo = new Video('PleaseWaitVideo');
        $waitingVideo->stream();
    }
}
else {
    $video->stream();
}
```

To make sure the player switches to live version of the video I would use the JS to ask the PHP script if the video is live every x seconds, and if yes make the player reload the stream and get scheduled video, not the waiting one.